# How to submit data on web form if button has only type and value using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following URL from which I want to pass some product number and get the current URL

https://www.skroutz.gr/

the form has

```
<form method="get" action="/search" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <p>
    <span class="search-bar-input-wrapper">
      <input type="search" name="keyphrase" id="search-bar-input" value="" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="γράψε τον όρο αναζήτησης">
      <span id="search-spinner" class="spinner"></span>
      <span class="icon clear-search hidden"></span>
    </span>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">
      Αναζήτηση
    </button>
  </p>
</form>
```

I used the following to submit search argument

```
records = []
listings =[]

Users = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; <Android Version>; <Build Tag etc.>) AppleWebKit/<WebKit Rev>(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/<Chrome Rev> Safari/<WebKit Rev>',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36']
RandomAgent = np.random.choice(Users)
opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=["+RandomAgent+"]")
br = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe',options=opts)


def current_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')

def mycontents():
    contents = []
    with open('sku_list.csv', 'r',encoding='utf-8',newline='') as csvf:
        reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            contents.append(row)  
        return contents


def get_the_link(myskus):

    br.get('https://www.skroutz.gr')
    for item in myskus:  
        search_url = br.find_element_by_id('search-bar-input')
        search_url.clear()
        search_url.send_keys(item) 
        WebDriverWait(br,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@value="submit"]'))).click()
        records.append(br.current_url)
    return records
```

but I get an error that the element cannot be found

How can I submit the form?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Αναζήτηση** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *XPATH 1* and `click()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action, 'search')]//button[.,'Αναζήτηση']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH 2* and `click()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action, 'search')]//button[normalize-space()='Αναζήτηση']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH 1* and `submit()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action, 'search')]//button[.,'Αναζήτηση']"))).submit()
  ```
- Using *XPATH 2* and `submit()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[contains(@action, 'search')]//button[normalize-space()='Αναζήτηση']"))).submit()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Is it bad if I use search_url.send_keys(item, Keys.ENTER) ?

Comment: Well, why to avoid the much effective and proven `click()` or `submit()`? At the end all that matters is to keep your tests non-flaky

Comment: I get for all Timeout Exception Error even if I do 20 to 10

Comment: Umm, _url_ is blocked at my workplace. Will provide working solution in a short while from home ;)

Answer (score 2):

Induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and below xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

for item in myskus:

   search_url = br.find_element_by_id('search-bar-input')
   search_url.clear()
   search_url.send_keys(item)
   WebDriverWait(br,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@value="submit"]'))).click()
   records.append(br.current_url)
```

---

This is the entire code I have tried and it provides me the output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
br=webdriver.Chrome()
br.get("https://www.skroutz.gr/")
myskus=['test','test1','abc']
records=[]
for item in myskus:

   search_url = br.find_element_by_id('search-bar-input')
   search_url.clear()
   search_url.send_keys(item)
   WebDriverWait(br,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//button[@value="submit"]'))).click()
   records.append(br.current_url)

print(records)
```

**Output**:

```
['https://www.skroutz.gr/search?keyphrase=test', 'https://www.skroutz.gr/search?keyphrase=test1', 'https://www.skroutz.gr/search?keyphrase=abc']
```

Comment: I get timeout exception

Comment: @MariaGeorgali : Don't know why is it not working with you.However you can try `search_url.submit()` instead of button click.